# Order SQL queries in a workload based on their complexity?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, complexity-theory, estimation

I have a SQL query workload, How can we order those queries based on their complexity?

I can think of the number of joins, the number of filters, number of tables accessed, number of filters, number of tuples per each table, and maybe the selectivity of the query.

How can I put this into a function that computes a complexity score for those queries?

Comment: What database are you using? Most if not all databases' execution plans provide an "estimated cost" (a synthetic number) of the execution of a query. I would get this cost for each query and use it for your scheduling. By the way, why do you want to actively plan this? What problem are you facing now?

Comment: Actually, I am working on  Spark-SQL, and I want a function that computes for each query an estimated complexity score.

Comment: You can retrieve the estimated cost of a query using `EXPLAIN COST <query>`. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-explain.html

Comment: Thanks, @TheImpaler, But is it possible to get a function that computes or estimate without running it, cause I assume that my implementation will be relational system-agnostic (Hive, Impala, Spark,. etc.)?

Comment: No, when it comes to optimization each engine is VERY different. It's not a piece of software you can just switch behind the scenes without noticing any difference. You'll probably need to learn to look under the hood for all those nasty details that, unfortunately, make all the difference. It's a lot of learning effort, but it pays off [after some time].

Comment: I see, but can't we have something like the Halstead functions to estimate the query complexity independently of the relational engine itself? Does it make sense to you

Comment: It's perfectly possible to do so, However, someone will need to do it for each engine. That includes designing it, taking into consideration all differences and quirks each engine has and model it well. On top of that each version of each database improves fast, so your model will be out of date quite fast if you don't re-work it constantly. I'm sure a lot of people would welcome an effort like this if someone could undertake it.